# Changing prop from nested parent's parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to change prop of my component if it is rendered more than once. By default the first prop will have fixed value but the second calling of the component will get it's prop from parent's parent. In my example, the value from `App.vue` doesn't change prop going in `myBox.vue`
Here is my [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-bush-29yjo?file=/src/components/myBox.vue:0-449)

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{years}}
    <myBox :years="years"/>
    <button @click="changeProp">Change prop</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import myBox from "./components/myBox";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    myBox
  },
  data() {
    return {
      years: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeProp() {
      this.years = 100;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

mySelect.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="select">
    <select>
      {{years}}
      <option v-for=" (i, index) in years" :key="index">{{i}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import myBox from "./myBox";
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  components: {
    myBox
  },
  props: ["years"]
};
</script>

<style>
.select {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
```

mySelect.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="box">
    <mySelect :years="24"/>
    <mySelect :years="24"/>
    <mySelect :years="24"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import mySelect from "./mySelect.vue";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //years: [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006],
      value: 5
    };
  },
  components: {
    mySelect
  }
};
</script>

<style>
div.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: lightblue;
}
</style>
```

Currently my code generates the second and thrid component dynamic with `v-if` and takes the default props value, whereas I want it to get from parent's parent.
Is it possible?